Телеграмм бот не запускается на сервере
Ситуация такая. Бот запускается на VDS сервере, все библиотеки установлены, в личные сообщения приходит сообщение о том что бот запущен, но он зависает на одном месте
INFO:main:Test - Запущен
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connecting to 111.111.111.11:111/TcpFull...
INFO:telethon.network.mtprotosender:Connection to 111.111.111.11:111/TcpFull complete!

и все, дальше он не запускается. Однако когда запускаю его на локалке, то все прекрасно работает
Помимо включения бота код должен запрашивать номер телефона и код подтверждения телеграмм чтобы войти в аккаунт и после этого в консоле должна появиться надпись Start Polling, но этого не происходит.
Сам же бот не на какие команды не реагирует. Только пишет что он запущен.
Опять же, локально на компьютере все прекрасно работает и запускается.
VDS сервер находится в Германии.
